# French letters on an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, encoding

I have a winForm application that generates an .aspx file based on the user input in the application. The problem happens when a user enters the French letters like "é", "à", "è", "â", "ù", "ô", "ê" and "ç".  It is supposed to look like a simple text on the page but it doesn't.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "It is supposed to look like a simple text"?  Do you mean the accented characters aren't displaying correctly, or that you want them stripped?

Comment: I'm slightly confused, are you trying to convert é to e for display, or is é coming out as &alt130 or something to that effect?

Comment: You have to give us more information before we can help you.  If it doesn't look like simple text, then what *does* it look like?

Comment: hi, I'm not from France. I don't know how this letters look like anyway, but my user (which happens to be from France) has this issue. He just said that the letters don't come out good. I assume that I would have to change my regional and language settings and then try to simulate the issue.

Comment: I assume that I need to check the encoding of my TextWritter object, which I use to write to my .aspx page, like Robert said. I apologize if I haven't been more clear. I am going to try that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the characters to be displayed with the accents, circumflexes, etc. try the following:

Add the following to the `<head>` of each (generated) page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Make sure that the .aspx files *themselves* are saved as UTF-8 files.

**Note:** I'm assuming here that an .aspx file is somewhat similar to a .jsp file. If that assumption is false, you should probably ignore this advice.

Comment: I was constantly trying that meta tag with charset=UTF-8, but haven't set the encoding of my textWritter, like you and the others suggest. So I think that TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("Default.aspx", false, Encoding.UTF8); will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating the .aspx file? If you're using a TextWriter, check the Encoding. If you're trying to write an array of bytes to a FileStream, be sure you use the right encoding when converting from  String to Byte[]. UTF-8 is usually the best encoding for the web.